# Early Exercised NSO Shares when company is acquired and the tender offer is lower than the strike price

Tags: united-states, income-tax, shares, capital-loss

I early exercised my company shares a few years ao at about $6/share and filed a 43(b) tax form.  I'm no longer at the company, but all my shares are vested.  This company was recently purchased by a private company offering a tender of $3/share.

I'm required to sell my shares by the end of the month at a loss.

Can I claim this loss when I file my 2017 income tax?  Is there anything I need to consider since it was an NSO, Early Exercised with 83(b) form?  I'm trying to minimize my loss as much as possible.

I'm also watching the share price to see if it goes above $3 so I can just sell instead of "accepting the tender."

Thank you!